# Running an Angular 14 project in VS: Error: Unknown arguments: port, ssl, ssl-cert, ssl-key

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I have a Client-Server-application in a VS project. When the project was created Angular 8 was the latest version. I ran into problems upgrading 8 to 14 and decided that it would be much easier to create a new project, install Angular 14 and copy all code to the new project. Now the client part of the application has been upgraded to Angular 14, so now I would like to move it to the original project.

I thought it would be as simple as copying over the ClientApp folder from the new VS project to the original one. Well, obviously it isn't, now I get an error message

```
InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was 
listening for requests. The error output was: Error: Unknown arguments: port, ssl, ssl-cert, ssl-key
```

[image: Screenshot error message]

I assume this has sth to do with the `package.json` file where it reads

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "prestart": "node aspnetcore-https",
    "start": "run-script-os",
    "start:windows": "ng serve --port 44455 --ssl --ssl-cert %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem --ssl-key %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key",
    "start:default": "ng serve --port 44455 --ssl --ssl-cert $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.pem --ssl-key $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.key",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run myproject:server:dev",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
```

If I take the line

```
ng serve --port 44455 --ssl --ssl-cert %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem --ssl-key %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key
```

replace the path to the certs and keys with their actual locations and run it, everything seems to be fine:

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:44455, open your browser on https://localhost:44455/ **


âˆš Compiled successfully.
```

I have Angular 14.2.4 (both local and global) and node v16.14.2.

I am running out of ideas, anyone could point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

What solved this issue for me is to install the latest version of node.
I uninstalled the current version of node (16) and installed the latest version.
18.12.1

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that no part of the directory where the key and certificate are located contains space i.e
C:\Users<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\https\angularapp.key.

But this might be difficult to achieve as the space in  might already exist from PC setup. In this scenario, what I suggest you do is to copy the key and cert to a new folder on C/ drive and manually change that line in package.json to this new location.

i.e:

```
"start:windows": "ng serve --port 44455 --ssl --ssl-cert C:\\NewFolder\angularapp.pem --ssl-key C:\\NewFolder\angularapp.key",
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs if the path referred to by `%npm_package_name%` contains spaces. To fix the problem, edit package.json and wrap (escaped) quotes around the paths for `--ssl-cert` and `--ssl-key`, as shown below:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "prestart": "node aspnetcore-https",
    "start": "run-script-os",
    "start:windows": "ng serve --port 44455 --ssl --ssl-cert \"%APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem\" --ssl-key \"%APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key\"",
    "start:default": "ng serve --port 44455 --ssl --ssl-cert \"$HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.pem\" --ssl-key \"$HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.key\"",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run myproject:server:dev",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
```

I reckon this is a bug in Visual Studio: It should wrap quotes around the paths when it auto-generates the package.json.