# Why ASP.NET with SPA Angular VS template doesn't run?

Tags: c#, angular

I wanted to try out and learn Angular using visual studio template(ASP.NET Core with Angular SPA) , but after I created the app (template) and hit run, it doesn't run like it supposed to.
Initially I was getting an error such as :
[image]
I've looked into similar issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73962009/running-an-angular-14-project-in-vs-error-unknown-arguments-port-ssl-ssl-ce) , and It seems to be the issue is the machine name that has a space in my case (`John Anthony`)
I've followed what is indicated there , and it wasn't compiling, instead I got this errors,

```
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:/Users/John Anthony/Desktop/Repositories/C#/Flights/Flights/ClientApp/src/app/nav-menu/nav-menu.component.css?ngResource' in 'C:\Users\John Anthony\Desktop\Repositories\C#\Flights\Flights\ClientApp'
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\John Anthony\Desktop\Repositories\C#\Flights\Flights\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=auto%3A&username=&password=&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=0&pathname=%2Fng-cli-ws&logging=info&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=false&live-reload=true' in 'C:\Users\John Anthony\Desktop\Repositories\C#\Flights\Flights\ClientApp'
Error: The loader "C:/Users/John Anthony/Desktop/Repositories/C#/Flights/Flights/ClientApp/src/app/nav-menu/nav-menu.component.css" didn't return a string.
```

Note: I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling nodejs and restarting my machine , I also tried this [one](https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm#upgrading-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why nobody answer this question, is it invalid?

Anyway, I fixed the problem by just updating the visual studio to the latest release (version 17.8.1 is where they fixed the issue), they have fixed the error on the update.
helpful links :
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Angular-and-ASPNET-Core-template-error:/10512806